# How to allow game players to upload images to a Unity game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I would like for players of my Unity game to be able to upload their own images into a game.  Any advice on how to do this or on where I can find information to do this.

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9960/how-do-i-let-the-user-select-a-local-file-for-my-a.html

Comment: it depends on which platform you work on

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm thinking about figuring out how to integrate Dropbox or Google Drive into my game.  That way it will hopefully be platform independent.